# How do I use the select( ) function to handle multiple clients in a server?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming

Is it possible to receive data from one client and send data to some other client at the same time using the `select()` function? How do I implement the timeout? How do I send and receive data from more than one client at the same time? I can understand how it can be done using `fork()`, but `select()` is confusing me.

P.S. Please forgive me if this question is not up to the level of Stack Overflow, but I did not find any good tutorial on `select()` and I am new to the socket programming world. Please help me out.

Comment: The way `select()` handles multiple clients is by monitoring all the clients at the same time and telling you when something happens for one of them (e.g., when one them has sent some data to you). You're not really handling multiple clients "at the same time" when you're using `select()` -- it's more like waiting for events related to multiple clients and handling them one at a time as they arrive. This is usually a better solution when you have a large number of clients, since having e.g. 10000 threads for 10000 simultaneous clients would be bad.

Answer (score 1):

To literally perform two actions at the same time, you need two threads (possibly, but not necessarily, belonging to different processes) running on a machine that has at least two CPU cores.  (In the separate process case you you don't need to explicitly manage threads; you can just rely on the processes' default threads.)  That's not what `select()` is for.  In fact, `select()` is mainly for *avoiding* that.

The `select()` function helps [a single thread of] a single process to efficiently service I/O over multiple channels by allowing it to recognize which channels are ready for reading and/or writing at any given time.  The program using `select()` queues up pending I/O requests, or otherwise knows somehow what I/O is needed, and loops, performing each operation only when `select()` informs it that the target I/O device is ready.  That allows it both to avoid blocking on I/O to devices that are unready while others are waiting for service, and to avoid wasting CPU by continuously polling devices to determine whether they are ready.

Comment: The computer can literally be sending and receiving data at the same time even with just a single thread, because data gets buffered inside the kernel.  So after your call to send() returns, the data the send() call passed to the kernel is still being sent out of the ethernet port while at the same time data is being received into a kernel buffer to be picked up by your next call to recv().

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, buffering has little to do with it, whether in the kernel or elsewhere.  You are correct, however, that I simplified a bit by focusing on the C language level, as seems appropriate in answer to the question posed.  It would be more precise to say that a single thread can execute only one function at a time, which is nearly a definition of "thread".  At the hardware level, it is true that device controllers serve as independent, special-purpose processors that effect physical I/O and buffering in parallel, and often asynchronously.

Comment: Could you give some code examples?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to receive data from one client and send data to some
>   other client at the same time using the select() function?

Yes (note that this is not the same as your program being blocked within a send() call and a recv() call at the same time -- that is not possible with a single thread, but fortunately it's not necessary either.  See my comment to John Bollinger's answer, above)

> How do I implement the timeout?

The first question is, why do you want to implement a timeout?  An efficient server does not need to depend on timeouts.

> How do I send and receive data from more than one client at the same
>   time?

Set all of your sockets to non-blocking mode, so that neither send() nor recv() will ever block; rather each will always return immediately.  That way there is no way that poor network connectivity to client A will cause your server to block for a long time (inside a recv() or send() call) and to stop responding to client B.

Once you've done that, the only place your program should *ever* block/wait is inside the select() call.  Set up your fd_set arguments so that select() returns whenever any of your sockets is ready-for-read, and also so that it returns whenever any of your sockets *that you have data ready to send to* is ready-for-write.

Once select() returns, use FD_ISSET() in a loop to find out which socket(s) have data ready for you to recv() and which are ready to accept some data from you (via send()).

Call recv() on each of the ready-for-read sockets to get some bytes of data from them.  Be aware that recv() may hand you any number of bytes less than or equal to the number you asked it to give you, and it may even return EWOULDBLOCK (if for some reason it didn't have any bytes to give you after all).

Call send() on each of the ready-for-write sockets to send some more bytes to them.  Again, be aware that send() may accept fewer bytes than you passed to it (its return value will tell you how many bytes it actually copied from your buffer into a kernel buffer), and it may also return EWOULDBLOCK (if for some reason it couldn't accept any bytes from you right now).

Then just repeat all of the above in a loop, and that's your single-threaded/multi-client server's event loop.  Note that this design requires you to keep send and receive buffers and explicit state variables for each connection to keep track of how many bytes are currently sent/received of the message you are currently sending/receiving, so it's a bit more work than the alternative (blocking) model where the blocking calls allow you use the thread's execution-location to help hold that state; but the upside is that you can have a single thread service many connections at once without the connections interfering with each other.